# Wordpress child theme accessing function from functions.php returns a different result

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, child-theming

I’ve created a child theme of the [Paloma FSE theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/paloma-fse/).

**functions.php:**

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'isPageFrontOrContact');
function isPageFrontOrContact() {
    if(is_page(55) || is_front_page()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**/patterns/footer-default.php**

```
<?php
var_dump(isPageFrontOrContact());
?>
```

When I invoke the `isPageFrontOrContact` function from `/patterns/footer-default.php`, the var_dump of the return value of the function always returns False.

For verification purposes, I added the `add_action` in `functions.php`. This shows me that the function is working correctly (albeit instantly shown at the top of the page). However when I manually invoke the `isPageFrontOrContact()` function from `/patterns/footer-default.php`, it does not know the page id so `is_page` always returns false.

Adding a `var_dump` of the global `$post` returns NULL as response.

Why is this not working when manually invoking the function declared in `functions.php` from my footer.php file?

Comment: After glancing through the theme code, including the original `/patterns/footer-default.php` - it looks like it's using a custom processing/template language of some sort.  I suspect the first time the file loads is at a time when the page isn't yet set, so you likely need to figure out how to call your functions using the unique syntax of the theme - eg. https://cmp.onl/tnZD.  Without dev-specific documentation or taking more time to review the code, it doesn't look very intuitive to extend.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know by any chance if this might be the new way of programming themes in Wordpress so they become FSE compatible? I've been out of the Wordpress theme development game for some years. That is why I could not figure this one out, and FSE seems to be quite new...

Comment: I ended up creating a different child theme based on twentytwentyone. The main take from this child theme is that I used some files like ``footer.php`` in the root directory of the theme where I am able to handle functions from function.php

Comment: Oh, good question re: FSE - I'm not sure either